# Java Fraction Calculator: Parsing

Tags: java

I'm doing a Java Fraction calculator for school, and one of the biggest problems I'm having is parsing. I can use it when I'm using only numbers, but since it is a fraction calculator, we include underscores(for mixed numbers) and backslashes for fractions. How would I be able to use the parse method while I'm using characters other than digits?
Mixed number example: 4_7/8

Comment: do `String.split` method calls on them and you should be able to go from there

Comment: Its easy to understand if you put some example.

Comment: Can you provide an example of using an underscore for a mixed number?

Comment: Added in an example of mixed number underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your parse method signature like this: `BigDecimal parse( String )`. For now, you can just have it return null. Next, write unit tests for various scenarios you need to support. Start out simple. While it is true that you need to be able to parse "-4_7/8", first make sure you can parse "7", "8", "-4", "7/8", and finally "-4_7/8". Be sure to consider edge cases as well. What will you do with "2/-3"? Will you parse that or consider that invalid input? An example test might look like this:

```
@Test
public final void verifyParseOne() {
    assertEquals(new BigDecimal(1), parse("10/10"));
}
```

Then, iteratively "fix" your `parse` function until it passes all of your tests. Hint: you should try to break down complex scenarios into simpler ones and you can do this by having your function call itself with a different parameter than the one it was given and performing some action on the result. E.g. Let's say your function already knows how to parse "7" and "8" correctly and you use it to create separate `BigDecimal` objects for the numerator and denominator. How can you turn those two objects into one?

Do **not** cheat by calling any of the `BigDecimal` constructors that take `char[]` or `String` as arguments.

Note, you do not need to use `BigDecimal`, you can create a similar domain object to represent numbers. But, that is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing, your main concern is: how are the different elements delimited - or what character(s) are used to partition the string. In your case the underscore character separates a whole number from it's fractional part and a backslash separates a numerator from a denominator.

With this in hand you can go about splitting a string into meaningful parts.

To parse the string, you can use, as @3kings mentioned, the `String.split()` method, that's one way.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

`String.split()` takes a regular expression as the delimiter to split on.

Let's say you received an input of `1_2/3` and stored it in a variable called `inputParts`, you could split it on the `_` character and return an array with 2 elements, `1` and `2/3`:

```
String[] inputParts = myInput.split("_");
```

Then you could split the fractional part, and return another array with 2 elements, `2` and `3`:

```
String[] fractionParts = inputParts[1].split("/");
```

You will need some logic to handle the different inputs you might receive. Sometimes you might only get a fraction, sometimes a whole number plus a fraction.